# Adding a class to Bootstrap Navbar Walker dropdown in WP

Tags: wordpress-theming, wp-nav-walker

Using Bootstrap 3 and Navbar Walker I am able to create dynamic dropdown on the Bootstrap and WP template but I need to add `.dropdown-menu-left` to the `.dropdown-menu` class, as well.

As you can see I tried this by addig this line

```
'dropdown_class'    => 'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left',
```

to the original code but apparently it is not functioning correctly.

```
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'desktop-main-menu',
            'theme_location'    => 'desktop-main-menu',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'desktop-navbar-main-collapse',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
            'dropdown_class'    => 'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
        );
    ?>
```

How can I add the `.dropdown-menu-left` ul?

Answer (score 0):

Just Update the `wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php` From

```
public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul role=\"menu\" class=\" dropdown-menu \" >\n";
}
```

To

```
public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul role=\"menu\" class=\" dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left\" >\n";
    }
```